# WinPcap doesn't collect any packets until Wireshark is started

Tags: sockets, networking, wireshark, winpcap

I'm trying to collect level 2 packets on my ethernet network.  The only thing happening on that network is that a device is spitting out ieee1722/AVB frames. 
 I've installed WinPcap, and started with the [most basic example](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut4.html).  Each call to `pcap_next_ex` is returning 0, indicating that no packets have been received.  I opened up Wireshark, and started monitoring on that interface -- and there, my program starts to receive packets.

I've tried this on two interfaces, the built in Intel I218-LM and a cheapo Ethernet-To-USB dongle.  Both interfaces connected the to AVB network do not return frames until I start monitoring in Wireshark on that interface.  Both will show the random office ethernet traffic when connected to that network, without the assist from Wireshark.

I've also tried calling `pcap_set_datalink` after `pcap_open` to set the link type to both `DLT_EN10MB` (no change) and `DLT_RAW` (function returns error).  None of the other types seemed relevant for me.

Of course, Wireshark uses WinPcap itself, but I cannot figure out what Wireshark is doing to make this work.  What's going on here?

**Update**: I noticed when my application exited, it also stopped the capture on Wireshark.  I can have both active at the same time, but my application needs to start capturing first.  I found Wireshark stops capturing after `pcap_finalldevs_ex` or `pcap_open_live` is called.  I can't find how Wireshark is initializing any different than I am, although their code is kind of hard to follow because of all the conditional enable/disable blocks.

Comment: I assume you've looked through the Wireshark source code already, but if you can't figure out what Wireshark is doing, then you might want to have a look at the WinDump source code instead?  See: https://www.winpcap.org/windump/install/default.htm and specifically the source code is at: https://www.winpcap.org/windump/install/bin/windump_3_9_5/WDumpSrc_3_9_5.zip

Comment: I have -- that's what lead me to try `pcap_set_datalink`.  I didn't follow everything in there too close, so I'm going to eventually backtrack there.

Comment: I just tried WinDump and that has the same behavior as my program -- no packets until I restart capture in Wireshark.  I think that means it's not a dumb oversight problem on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had a very old version of Nmap for Windows installed which includes  npcap that can be used in place of winpcap.  I uninstalled npcap, rebooted, and now my application works just fine.